# MDM API Integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, mdm, installed-applications

I am trying to do an enterprise application which need to list all the installed apps in iPhone and also should allow the user to delete some apps from current application.I know this is not possible using any direct API's.But I found that using MDM API's it is possible. I had gone through the documents about this in apple's website http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_OTA_Enrollment_Configuration.pdf

But I am not sure where I need to start. What are the steps I need to follow to access these APIs in the iPhone side. Do I need to perform all these steps programatically when I open the app or else these will be handled by server.

Please share your ideas about how to implement this from a developer point of view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apps are not able to do any MDM, it can only be done by the server, that is managing the device.

Apple has a session video from WWDC 2010 that shows how this is done.